# Not able to download new version of my app from appstore, I am able to download other apps

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, version, updates

I have pushed new build yesterday and it went live today. But I am not able to download my new version from app store, same time I am able to download other apps. Can someone please help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you mean when  you say that you are not able to download? like do you get any error message? Does the download icon just keep spinning, etc.?

Comment: @7vikram7 Download icon spins for few seconds and stops.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes you need to wait a few hours and I don't know why.

Comment: Its been few hours now. According to my knowledge if you can see app in appstore then you should able to download it.